# How to create a create-react-app after deleting an old create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
(base) Dun-Yan:Web development.HTML ongdunyan$ sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
Password:

up to date, audited 1 package in 429ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
(base) Dun-Yan:Web development.HTML ongdunyan$ sudo npm install -global create-react-app@17.0.0
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for create-react-app@17.0.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ongdunyan/.npm/_logs/2021-11-29T13_27_38_046Z-debug.log
(base) Dun-Yan:Web development.HTML ongdunyan$
```

I have deleted the create-react-app file in vs code and through the terminal of my Mac. Why is there still error and why is my file create-react-app not created

Answer (score 0):

React  and create-react-app are 2 different things

while react is on version 17, create-react-app ( a script for bootstrapping react-apps) is on version 4.0.3

please run `npm I -g create-react-app`

Comment: There is still error after I typed i or I

Comment: what error are you getting now ?